# François Viète's approximation to π

Tags: number-theory, approximation, products

How do I program the approximation to π devised by François Viète, which is given by

```
2 * 2/Sqrt[2] * 2/Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[2]] * 2/Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[2]]] * ...
```

using some of these functions: `Nest`, `For`, `Module`, `Product`, `Do`?

Comment: I appreciate all of your answers, but these commands are not in the list I posted... Right now, I have come to this: PieApprox[n_] := 2/Nest[Sqrt[# + 2] &, Sqrt[2], n]. So I was thinking if someone could help me plug in the Product fonction to finish it, because I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Xavier please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 16):

You could use

```
VietePiApprox[n_] := (Times @@ NestList[Sqrt[2 + #] &, Sqrt[2], n])/ 2^(n + 1)
SetAttributes[VietePiApprox, Listable]
```

which approximates Pi as follows.

```
N[VietePiApprox[Range[5]] - 2/\[Pi]]
```

> {0.0166617, 0.00410909, 0.0010238, 0.000255735, 0.0000639204}

Answer (score 9):

Well, `FoldList` also can finish this job:

```
2/Times @@ (1/2 FoldList[Sqrt[2 + #] &, ConstantArray[Sqrt[2.], 10]])
```

By the way, by putting the one half just before `NestList`, `FoldList` can save one's effort for counting the number of twos in the denominators.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear[VietePiApprox];
VietePiApprox[n_] := Product[FunctionExpand[Cos[Pi/2^(i + 1)]], {i, 1, n}];
Table[VietePiApprox[i], {i, 1, 10}]
% - 2.0/Pi
```

> {0.070487, 0.0166617, 0.00410909, 0.0010238, 0.000255735, \
>   0.0000639204, 0.0000159792, 3.99476*10^-6, 9.98687*10^-7, 
>    2.49671*10^-7}